# Dismiss modal when completing a flow on Mobile

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, modal-windows

I am working on a mobile app and the flow is mainly to add one or n accounts. The flow has 3 steps and you can't jump to the next step if you haven't filled the previous one.
When designing the flow I found that if I press the cross button by mistake i loose everything, so I added a confirmation modal to not loose our users.
What do you think? is it something very common on mobile?

Thanks!

[image: The drawer I designed]

Comment: I have seen it used in apps, I've also seen apps that do not use it but remember what you entered before you closed the form.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the wording of the message. I find the way it is worded at the moment to be unclear what happens when you press cancel, will I cancel the flow or will I cancel my exit? For instance changing the options to Yes / No and changing the text to show 'exit' instead of cancel might be better. (could not edit my last comment anymore).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the wording is not final in this screen but you are right. We can also have : Are you sure you want to discard this event?
And 2 CTAs : Discard / Keep going

But still, we have a technical writer who's going to take care of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find confirmation dialogues intrusive, and I notice that users often click ok without reading them.

What about persisting the information entered in the dialogue when it is canceled? When the user chooses that option again, what they entered last time is still there, so they can continue where they left off, or hit reset to clear the old data.